# How to get product list of published applications for user to purchase ( InAppPurchase - android)

Tags: in-app-purchase

I want to get product list of published application from google play in my application so that user can get updated product list on google play and can purchase.

I am working on an application in which i have to implement IAP- InAppPurchase service provide 
by google play. I compiled a sample code and it is working fine. Now i want to now how can get 
product list(to purchase product list for users in applicant) under my app on google play. when users go for purchase they should view updated product list in application as like product list on google play under this application.

Is it possible to get updated product list from google play in application every time when users go for purchase any product?

if it possible then provide that piece of code.

Please help me or suggest any option.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible to get product list of publish app. but you can get updated price or detail of that product list. for that you need to store product id in local then you can get updated product details using query Inventory.